# What is the best way to track changes in a form via javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms

I'd like to track changes in inputs in a form via javascript. My intent is (but not limited) to

- enable "save" button only when something has changed
- alert if the user wants to close the page and something is not saved

Ideas?

Comment: I know I'm 5 years late here, but I think I can improve on the previous solutions... I just fixed and updated my answer below.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Loop through all the input elements, and put an `onchange` handler on each. When that fires, set a flag which lets you know the form has changed. A basic version of that would be very easy to set up, but wouldn't be smart enough to recognize if someone changed an input from "a" to "b" and then back to "a". If it were important to catch that case, then it'd still be possible, but would take a bit more work.

Here's a basic example in jQuery:

```
$("#myForm")
    .on("input", function() {
        // do whatever you need to do when something's changed.
        // perhaps set up an onExit function on the window
        $('#saveButton').show();
    })
;
```

Comment: You could use a closure in your loop to store the value of the input field, and then you can test to see if the input changed back to the value.  You'll have to do some special cases for radio buttons, checkboxes and the submitbutton though.  OH, and don't forget to remove the unbink in this case!

Comment: AFAIK, the change event is only triggered for e.g. a text input if the contents is changed and _the input loses focus_. This would mean the save button is not enabled until the user e.g. hits tab or so, wouldn't it ?

Comment: @ssc, yep that's correct. Most forms would probably have more than one field though.

Comment: @nickf which is an issue for the last field in the form.  The user will have filled out the field and will wonder why the submit button still looks disabled :(  It's not apparent that they have to click-somewhere-or-tab to be able to proceed until they actually click-somewhere-or-tab.  Bad UX design.

Comment: Dont think it is a type.. I guess the right method is one indeed. http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: What about TextArea and other kind of input field ?

Comment: @jinglesthula so what is the solution to this problem? Is this script usable or does it fail to record the final field's changes?

Comment: You can use the `input` event, which has better browser support today compared to 8 years ago. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input That fires on every change to the field, including typing, deleting, pasting, etc.

Comment: This will surely ommit any other kind of field other than `input` (for example `select`)

Answer (score 18):

Text form elements in JS expose a `.value` property and a `.defaultValue` property, so you can easily implement something like:

```
function formChanged(form) {
  for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
      if(form.elements[i].value != form.elements[i].defaultValue) return(true);
  }
  return(false);
}
```

For checkboxes and radio buttons see whether `element.checked != element.defaultChecked`, and for HTML `<select />` elements you'll need to loop over the `select.options` array and check for each option whether `selected == defaultSelected`.

You might want to look at using a framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to attach handlers to the `onchange` event of each individual form element. These handlers can call your `formChanged()` code and modify the `enabled` property of your "save" button,  and/or attach/detach an event handler for the document body's `beforeunload` event.

Comment: Instead of looping over the options you could do something like this:

select.options[select.selectedIndex].defaultSelected;

which will tell you if the selected index is selected by default or not

Answer (score 10):

Here's a javascript & jquery method for detecting form changes that is simple. It disables the submit button until changes are made. It detects attempts to leave the page by means other than submitting the form. It accounts for "undos" by the user, it is encapsulated within a function for ease of application, and it doesn't misfire on submit. Just call the function and pass the ID of your form.

This function serializes the form once when the page is loaded, and again before the user leaves the page. If the two form states are different, the prompt is shown.

Try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/skibulk/ev5rE/

```
function formUnloadPrompt(formSelector) {
    var formA = $(formSelector).serialize(), formB, formSubmit = false;

    // Detect Form Submit
    $(formSelector).submit( function(){
        formSubmit = true;
    });

    // Handle Form Unload    
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        if (formSubmit) return;
        formB = $(formSelector).serialize();
        if (formA != formB) return "Your changes have not been saved.";
    };

    // Enable & Disable Submit Button
    var formToggleSubmit = function(){
        formB = $(formSelector).serialize();
        $(formSelector+' [type="submit"]').attr( "disabled", formA == formB);
    };

    formToggleSubmit();
    $(formSelector).change(formToggleSubmit);
    $(formSelector).keyup(formToggleSubmit);
}



// Call function on DOM Ready:

$(function(){
    formUnloadPrompt('form');
});
```

Comment: Years later. :-) I love this, but it doesn't account for checkboxes and select elements (haven't checked radio butons).

Comment: @Charles Make sure all of your form elements have proper names. Fiddle updated.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
function isModifiedForm(form){
  var __clone = $(form).clone();
  __clone[0].reset();
  return $(form).serialize() == $(__clone).serialize();
}
```

Hope its helps ))

Comment: While this is short and sweet, it covers only the situation where the initial form is empty - see the docs for [reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset).

Answer (score 2):

If your using a web app framework (rails, ASP.NET, Cake, symfony), there should be packages for ajax validation,

http://webtecker.com/2008/03/17/list-of-ajax-form-validators/

and some wrapper on onbeforeunload() to warn users taht are about to close the form:

http://pragmatig.wordpress.com/2008/03/03/protecting-userdata-from-beeing-lost-with-jquery/
[Detecting Unsaved Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155739/detecting-unsaved-changes-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

I answered a question like this on Ars Technica, but the question was framed such that the changes needed to be detected even if the user does not blur a text field (in which case the change event never fires). I came up with a comprehensive script which:

1. enables submit and reset buttons if field values change
2. disables submit and reset buttons if the form is reset
3. interrupts leaving the page if form data has changed and not been submitted
4. supports IE 6+, Firefox 2+, Safari 3+ (and presumably Opera but I did not test)

This script depends on Prototype but could be easily adapted to another library or to stand alone.

```
$(document).observe('dom:loaded', function(e) {
    var browser = {
        trident: !!document.all && !window.opera,
        webkit: (!(!!document.all && !window.opera) && !document.doctype) ||
            (!!window.devicePixelRatio && !!window.getMatchedCSSRules)
    };

    // Select form elements that won't bubble up delegated events (eg. onchange)
    var inputs = $('form_id').select('select, input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"]');

    $('form_id').observe('submit', function(e) {
        // Don't bother submitting if form not modified
        if(!$('form_id').hasClassName('modified')) {
            e.stop();
            return false;
        }
        $('form_id').addClassName('saving');
    });

    var change = function(e) {
        // Paste event fires before content has been pasted
        if(e && e.type && e.type == 'paste') {
            arguments.callee.defer();
            return false;
        }

        // Check if event actually results in changed data
        if(!e || e.type != 'change') {
            var modified = false;
            $('form_id').getElements().each(function(element) {
                if(element.tagName.match(/^textarea$/i)) {
                    if($F(element) != element.defaultValue) {
                        modified = true;
                    }
                    return;
                } else if(element.tagName.match(/^input$/i)) {
                    if(element.type.match(/^(text|hidden)$/i) && $F(element) != element.defaultValue) {
                        modified = true;
                    } else if(element.type.match(/^(checkbox|radio)$/i) && element.checked != element.defaultChecked) {
                        modified = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            if(!modified) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Mark form as modified
        $('form_id').addClassName('modified');

        // Enable submit/reset buttons
        $('reset_button_id').removeAttribute('disabled');
        $('submit_button_id').removeAttribute('disabled');

        // Remove event handlers as they're no longer needed
        if(browser.trident) {
            $('form_id').stopObserving('keyup', change);
            $('form_id').stopObserving('paste', change);
        } else {
            $('form_id').stopObserving('input', change);
        }
        if(browser.webkit) {
            $$('#form_id textarea').invoke('stopObserving', 'keyup', change);
            $$('#form_id textarea').invoke('stopObserving', 'paste', change);
        }
        inputs.invoke('stopObserving', 'change', arguments.callee);
    };

    $('form_id').observe('reset', function(e) {
        // Unset form modified, restart modified check...
        $('reset_button_id').writeAttribute('disabled', true);
        $('submit_button_id').writeAttribute('disabled', true);
        $('form_id').removeClassName('modified');
        startObservers();
    });

    var startObservers = (function(e) {
        if(browser.trident) {
            $('form_id').observe('keyup', change);
            $('form_id').observe('paste', change);
        } else {
            $('form_id').observe('input', change);
        }
        // Webkit apparently doesn't fire oninput in textareas
        if(browser.webkit) {
            $$('#form_id textarea').invoke('observe', 'keyup', change);
            $$('#form_id textarea').invoke('observe', 'paste', change);
        }
        inputs.invoke('observe', 'change', change);
        return arguments.callee;
    })();

    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
        if($('form_id').hasClassName('modified') && !$('form_id').hasClassName('saving')) {
            return 'You have unsaved content, would you really like to leave the page? All your changes will be lost.';
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: if the user does not blur a changed text field: onkeyup() and store changed value.

Answer (score 1):

To alert the user before closing, use unbeforeunload:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   return "You are about to lose your form data.";
};
```

Comment: Just return the string. The browser will confirm() it.

Comment: But this also giving alert if I hit save button. Any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I would store each fields value in a variable when the page loads, then compare those values when the user unloads the page. If any differences are detected you will know what to save and better yet, be able to specifically tell the user what data will not be saved if they exit.

```
// this example uses the prototype library
// also, it's not very efficient, I just threw it together
var valuesAtLoad = [];
var valuesOnCheck = [];
var isDirty = false;
var names = [];
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    $$('.field').each(function(i) {
        valuesAtLoad.push($F(i));
    });
});

var checkValues = function() {
    var changes = [];
    valuesOnCheck = [];
    $$('.field').each(function(i) {
        valuesOnCheck.push($F(i));
    });

    for(var i = 0; i <= valuesOnCheck.length - 1; i++ ) {
        var source = valuesOnCheck[i];
        var compare = valuesAtLoad[i];
        if( source !== compare ) {
            changes.push($$('.field')[i]);
        }
    }

    return changes.length > 0 ? changes : [];
};

setInterval(function() { names = checkValues().pluck('id'); isDirty = names.length > 0; }, 100);

// notify the user when they exit
Event.observe(window, 'beforeunload', function(e) {
     e.returnValue = isDirty ? "you have changed the following fields: \r\n" + names + "\r\n these changes will be lost if you exit. Are you sure you want to continue?" : true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used dirtyforms.js.  Works well for me.

http://mal.co.nz/code/jquery-dirty-forms/

Answer (score 1):

I did some Cross Browser Testing.

On Chrome and Safari this is nice:

```
<form onchange="validate()">
...
</form>
```

For Firefox + Chrome/Safari I go with this:

```
<form onkeydown="validate()">
    ...
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="validate()">
</form>
```

Items like checkboxes or radiobuttons need an own onchange event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event handler to each form input/select/textarea's onchange event. Setting a variable to tell you if you should enable the "save" button. Create an onunload hander that checks for a dirty form too, and when the form is submitted reset the variable:

```
window.onunload = checkUnsavedPage;
var isDirty = false;
var formElements = //Get a reference to all form elements
for(var i = 0; len = formElements.length; i++) {
    //Add onchange event to each element to call formChanged()
}

function formChanged(event) {
    isDirty = false;
    document.getElementById("savebtn").disabled = "";
}

function checkUnsavedPage() {
    if (isDirty) {
        var isSure = confirm("you sure?");  
        if (!isSure) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full implementation of [Dylan Beattie's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194101/what-is-the-best-way-to-track-changes-in-a-form-via-javascript#194112):

[Client/JS Framework for "Unsaved Data" Protection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140460/clientjs-framework-for-unsaved-data-protection#140508)

You shouldn't need to store initial values to determine if the form has changed, unless you're populating it dynamically on the client side (although, even then, you could still set up the `default` properties on the form elements).

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out this jQuery plugin I built at [jQuery track changes in forms plugin](http://code.zhandwa.com/jquery/)

See the demo [here](http://downloads.zhandwa.com/trackchanges/demo/) and download the JS [here](http://downloads.zhandwa.com/trackchanges/demo/js/jquery.form.track.changes.js)

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using jQuery, see my answer a similar question: 
[Disable submit button unless original form data has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593222/disable-submit-button-unless-original-form-data-has-changed/16594431#16594431).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge and i was thinking of a common solution. The code below is not perfect, its from initial r&d. Following are the steps I used:

1) Move the following JS to a another file (say changeFramework.js)

2) Include it in your project by importing it

3) In your html page, whichever control needs monitoring, add the class "monitorChange"

4) The global variable 'hasChanged' will tell, if there is any change in the page you working on.

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="MonitorChangeFramework">
// MONITOR CHANGE FRAMEWORK
// ALL ELEMENTS WITH CLASS ".monitorChange" WILL BE REGISTERED FOR CHANGE
// ON CHANGE IT WILL RAISE A FLAG
var hasChanged;

function MonitorChange() {
    hasChanged = false;
    $(".monitorChange").change(function () {
        hasChanged = true;
    });
}
```

Following are the controls where I used this framework:

```
<textarea class="monitorChange" rows="5" cols="10" id="testArea"></textarea></br>
        <div id="divDrinks">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chb monitorChange" value="Tea" />Tea </br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="chb monitorChange" value="Milk" checked='checked' />Milk</br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="chb monitorChange" value="Coffee" />Coffee </br>
        </div>
        <select id="comboCar" class="monitorChange">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
        <button id="testButton">
            test</button><a onclick="NavigateTo()">next >>> </a>
```

I believe there can be huge improvement in this framework. Comment/Changes/feedbacks are welcome. :)