# observing Attribute change in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mutation-observers

I am trying to observe a change to

```
<div id="one" class="elem" data-result="inr"></div>
```

data-result attribute in this div.

Most of the older methods seem to have been depreciated. I realised that MutationObserver is the best way to proceed. and wrote one on my own which did not work. I found the [onattrchange.js](http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/)  which is similar.

With this I am trying to solve the problem I face.

I have created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zFVyv/187/) which is able to detect input changes (using $(document).on), but not the changes to data-result attribute.

I have tried two ways... (1) `('body').attrchange`
                         (2) `$(document).on('attrchange',...)`

I am not sure why this does not work. ( I am also pretty new to js and jquery, learning by coding)

edit: I have found a similar [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PV8jj/12/) which does exactly what I want to. I am doing something similar but I guess I have made some small mistake.

Comment: Why not just use `trigger` to manually raise an event when you change the `data` attribute?

Comment: In the jsfiddle, I am using an input box for testing. In my application the data-result will be modified using jQuery.

Comment: You may like this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240592/is-it-possible-to-listen-for-changes-to-an-objects-attributes-in-javascript - see the very first answered question.

Comment: This link is interesting. I am trying to understand and add it to my jsfiddle to see if it works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem with the code.

The [onattrchange.js](https://github.com/meetselva/attrchange/raw/master/attrchange.js) does not seem to identify changes made using

```
$("element").data("result",$(this).val());
```

It detects

```
$("element").attr("data-result",$(this).val());
```

I have added the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zFVyv/192/).

Comment: jQuery `data` function does not uses/creates an attribute. The attrchange plugin listens to DOM attribute changes on an element.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for same solution, but didn't wanted to use any 3rd party library.
After digging out little bit on google as well as on this site, I found solution on https://stackoverflow.com/a/58501827/6879925

```js
// code to change image src in each 1000ms.
count = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    var sourceElement = document.querySelector('#div1');
    sourceElement.setAttribute('data-src', 'something' + count);
    sourceElement.innerHTML = 'something' + count;
    count++;
}, 2000);

function startMutationObserver(tNode, c) {
    // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
    const targetNode = tNode ? tNode : document;

    // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
    const config = c ? c : {
        attributes: true,
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    };

    // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
    const callback = function (mutationsList, observer) {
        for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
            if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                targetNode.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('newChild', {
                    detail: mutation
                }));
            } else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
                targetNode.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('attributeChange', {
                    detail: mutation
                }));
            }
        }
    }
    // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
    const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

    // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
    observer.observe(targetNode, config);

    // Later, you can stop observing
    // observer.disconnect();
}
// call this function to start observing DOM element change
startMutationObserver(document);

// code to listen custom event and filter custom event as per requirement
document.addEventListener('attributeChange', function (e) {
    // console.log(e);
    const ele = e.detail;

    if (ele.target.matches('div[data-src]') && ele.attributeName == 'data-src') {

        var src = e.detail.target.getAttribute('data-src');

        console.log('new src=', src);

    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='div1' data-src="something">Something....</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I think this is one of the best solution I ever got for attribute change detection in HTML/javaScript.

Comment: Welcome to SO, posing link only answers can not be consider as a valid answer, please provide a sample code to show how the problem can be solved.

Comment: @SaeedZhiany, thanks for you suggestion, Added sample code too in the answer.