# Updated text fields to JSON string - Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a dynamic form that has text fields which change to input boxes when they need to be updated.

When they have been updated and the user clicks submit I want to add the updated values to a json string which i can post to an ASP.NET script.

Here is the html of 2 rows in the table:

```
<tr id="1">
<td onclick="">Colleague 1:</td>
<td id="c1nametxt" onclick="">
    <input id="c1nametb" type="text" value="Bob">
</td>
<td id="c1unametxt" onclick="">
    <input id="c1unametb" type="text" value="bjones">
</td>
<td id="c1eaddtxt" onclick="">
    <input id="c1eaddtb" type="text" value="bjones@company.co.uk">
</td>
<td id="c1pnotxt" onclick="">
    <input id="c1pnotb" type="text" value="0111122224">
</td>
<td id="c1exttxt" onclick="">
    <input id="c1exttb" type="text" value="22224">
    <span onclick="delrec(this)">Del</span>
</td>
```

```
<tr id="2">
     <td onclick="">Colleague 2:</td>
<td id="c2nametxt" onclick="">
    <input id="c2nametb" type="text" value="John">
</td>
<td id="c2unametxt" onclick="">
    <input id="c2unametb" type="text" value="jhill">
</td>
<td id="c2eaddtxt" onclick="">
    <input id="c2eaddtb" type="text" value="jhill@company.co.uk">
</td>
<td id="c2pnotxt" onclick="">
    <input id="c2pnotb" type="text" value="0111122225">
</td>
<td id="c2exttxt" onclick="">
    <input id="c2exttb" type="text" value="22225">
    <span onclick="delrec(this)">Del</span>
</td>
```

Here is the jQuery I'm using to detect which input boxes have been updated:

```
$("#subdetails").click(function () {
    $("#mantab input[type=text]").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() !== this.defaultValue) {               

             //code to create json string   

        }
    });
 });
```

This is an example of a json string i would like to create if the following field were updated:

```
{
"1":{
    "c1nametb": "newname",
    "c1exttb": "22227",
    }
"2":{
    "c2eaddtb": "neweadd@company.co.uk",
    "c2pnotb": "0111122210",
    }
}
```

Can any one please help me with the code to create this string, or advise on a better way of doing this?

Thanks
Ryan

Comment: I only want to convert the updated fields into a string and not the whole form.

Comment: Maintain an array (or object) that stores a boolean for each field and flips the value to true when a field is updated.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194101/what-is-the-best-way-to-track-changes-in-a-form-via-javascript)...

Comment: I am already able to check which fields have been updated by comparing the defaultvalue to current value.

Comment: its just getting those specific fields into a json string which i can pass to an asp.net scipt

Comment: but it the format above

Comment: So, use the logic in the duplicate question and modify it slightly to only include modified values.

Comment: Have you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery/39248551#39248551

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution, iterate through each row, find values of textbox and push it to array and finally convert it to string. you can set that string in hidden field to pass it to server side.

```
var ArrColleague = [];

$("#subdetails").click(function () {
    $("#mantab tr").each(function (index, val) {
        ArrColleague.push({
            "c1nametb": $(val).find("#c" + $(val).attr("id") + "nametb").val(),
            "c1unametb": $(val).find("#c" + $(val).attr("id") + "unametb").val(),
            "c1eaddtb": $(val).find("#c" + $(val).attr("id") + "eaddtb").val(),
            "c1pnotb": $(val).find("#c" + $(val).attr("id") + "pnotb").val(),
            "c1exttb": $(val).find("#c" + $(val).attr("id") + "exttb").val()
        });
    });
});

var JsonString = JSON.stringify(ArrColleague);
```