# How can I ask a web user for confirmation if he really wants to leave the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I ask the user *Are you sure you want to leave the page?*

Like for example if you click the back button while asking a question on Stackoverflow?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense, do you mean it checks the question without pressing the submit button?

Comment: I think he means the confirmation dialog you get when you're half-way through writing a question on SO and hit your browser back button

Comment: @Elliott, the question makes a lot sense. If there is text in the "Your answer" box and you navigate away from the page, even with browser back, it will alert you.

Comment: Manos is right, and I guess Question is right why I got down ?

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own) has what you're looking for. Which points to [this even more pertinent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140460/client-js-framework-for-unsaved-data-protection). And here is [one more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299452/how-do-i-stop-a-page-from-unloading-navigating-away-in-js)

Comment: Note the title on the vote buttons: "This question is unclear or not useful" - the fact that the commenters needed to pry the meaning of the question out of you probably means your question is unclear - and some people here downvote unclear questions.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317273/warn-user-before-leaving-web-page-with-unsaved-changes

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is to bind an event handler to the "unload" JavaScript event. jQuery makes this very easy to do with its [.unload() event handler](http://api.jquery.com/unload/). In the method you bind you can check to see if any the page's form fields have text input. Assuming they do pop an alert notifying the user they'll lose any unsaved data if they navigate from the page.

This method will fire an alert whenever the user navigates away from the page for any reason.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
  alert('Handler for .beforeunload() called.');
});
```

That's obviously not very user friendly but a couple of quick modifications can make it workable to your question.

Comment: I think you'll find the `unload` event is too late to prevent the user from leaving. You need to use the `onbeforeunload` event. Also you can't use jquery to bind to `onbeforeunload` in all browsers

Comment: so you wanna say to use pure JavaScript instead jquery because of browser compatibility

Comment: @MakDotGNU - see the questions linked to in my answer.

Comment: @rojoca updated to use `beforeunload`. Didn't realize `unload` was too late. Thanks for the tip.