# How does StackOverflow implement a pop-up box before you close the tab while you are writing an answer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I ask a web user for confirmation if he really wants to leave the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998603/how-can-i-ask-a-web-user-for-confirmation-if-he-really-wants-to-leave-the-page)

When I am writing an answer to something on SE, I commonly stumble on my back button (which is annoyingly positioned next to my arrow keys) which takes me back a tab, on other websites, losing all the text I just types.

However on SE, when I am about to leave a page, it creates a **pop-up** to ask if I really intended on doing this, which is super useful.

How is this implemented?